# iOS Push Notifications with Firebase Topic Messages are not making it to the device

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm attempting to send an iOS push notification to a topic in Firebase using node.js.  I followed [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html), but can't figure out why the notification isn't making it to the devices subscribed to the topic. I am able to send topic messages from the console and `listenForNotificationRequests()` is removing the `notificationRequest` children successfully.

Here is the structure of the notification request in Firebase:

[image: example notification request]

Here is the node.js code with keys/urls removed:

```
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require('request');

var API_KEY = "APIKEYREMOVED"; // Your Firebase Cloud Messaging Server API key

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("./pathToJSON");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "URL_REMOVED"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child("notificationRequests");
  requests.on("child_added", function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
    sendNotificationToUser(
      request.username,
      request.message,
      function() {
        requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
      }
    );
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization": "key="+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      to : "/topics/user_"+username,
      priority : "high",
      notification: {
        title: message
      }
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}

// start listening
listenForNotificationRequests();
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Here is how I'm subscribing to the topic in Swift:

```html
FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "user_\(currentUserID!)")
```

Comment: NodeJS code looks okay. Could you also put in your client side code for subscription? Are you receiving a success response after sending the message?

Comment: Does it matter that there is a space in ' application/json'?

Comment: @AL. Added the client side code for topic subscription.  I've confirmed the subscriptions are working by successfully sending and receiving topic messages from the console.  I'm deploying the node.js app to Google Cloud App Engine.  Still trying to figure out how to debug there.  Is that where I should focus?

Comment: @PeterTao I've deployed a version with that space included but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: This tutorial is for Android. Are you sure this works for iOS?

Comment: @PeterTao The "Summary" section of the tutorial has additional direction for iOS devices, which I've followed and implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anybody who runs across this, I found the issue.  I had to add "text" into the notification payload, which populates the body of the notification. The tutorial only includes "title", which is optional and not sufficient by itself...at least for APNS from what I've read.

Thanks to those who answered!

```js
function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization": "key="+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "priority" : "high",
      "notification" : {
        "title": sender,
        "text": message
      },
      "to" : "/topics/user_"+username
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having a problem sending push notifications to a topic, and I'm structuring the request as you are in your solution, but I'm getting an `"error":"InvalidRegistration"` error. Did you specify any other authorizatons apart from the server key? Would pleas check my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402581/errorinvalidregistration-error-while-sending-message-to-fcm-post-swift ?