# "error":"InvalidRegistration" error while sending message to FCM post swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm adapting a working device to device function in order to send push notifications to topics. When I send a push to FcmToken it works perfectly, but when I sent it to a topic I get an `"error":"InvalidRegistration"`error. Is this registration related to the server key or what registration I'm missing to send with the request? 
 Can you see where I'm mistaking?
As always many thanks.

Here is the working function to the `fcmToken` :

```
static func sendPushNotification(to receiverToken: String, title: String, subtitle: String, body: String) {
            let serverKey = firebaseServerKey // AAAA8c3j2...
//            let topic = "/topics/<your topic here>"  // replace it with partnerToken if you want to send a topic
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")

        let postParams: [String : Any] = [
                "to": receiverToken,
                "notification": [
//                    "badge" : 1, sendig the badge number, will cause aglitch
                    "body": body,
                    "title": title,
                    "subtitle": subtitle,
                    "sound" : true, // or specify audio name to play
                    "content_available": true, // this will call didReceiveRemoteNotification in receiving app, else won't work
                    "priority": "high"
//                    "click_action" : "", // action when user click notification (categoryIdentifier)
                ],
                "data" : [
                    "data": "ciao",
            ]
                ]

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            do {
//                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: [.prettyPrinted]) // working
                print("My paramaters: \(postParams)")
            } catch {
                print("Caught an error: \(error)")
            }


            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                if let realResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    if realResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                        print("Not a 200 response")
                    }
                }

                if let postString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {
                    print("POST: \(postString)")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
```

and this is the one for topics:

```
    static func sendTopicPushNotification(to topic: String, title: String, subtitle: String, body: String) {
        let serverKey = firebaseServerKey // AAAA8c3j2...
        //            let topic = "/topics/<your topic here>"  // replace it with partnerToken if you want to send a topic
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")

        let postParams: [String : Any] = [
            "priority": "high",
            "notification": [
                //                    "badge" : 1, sendig the badge number, will cause aglitch
                "body": body,
                "title": title,
                "subtitle": subtitle,
                "text": "some text",
                "sound" : true, // or specify audio name to play

                //                    "click_action" : "", // action when user click notification (categoryIdentifier)
            ],
            "to" : "topics/Bologna/Shop-promotions"
//            "data" : [
////                "data": "ciao",
//                "body": body,
//                "title": title,
//                "subtitle": subtitle,
//            ]
        ]


        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
//        request.httpMethod = "POST" // error: POST: {"error":"InvalidParameters: Bad topic or filter provided"}
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        do {
            //                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: [.prettyPrinted]) // working
            print("sendTopicPushNotification : My paramaters: \(postParams)")
        } catch {
            print("sendTopicPushNotification : Caught an error: \(error)")
        }


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let realResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if realResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    print("sendTopicPushNotification : Not a 200 response : \(realResponse)")
                }
                print("sendTopicPushNotification : response : \(realResponse)")
            }

            if let postString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {
                print("sendTopicPushNotification : POST: \(postString)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found where the problem was. Topics can't be defined in trees as I thought and I was missing `/` at the beginning so changing from `"to" : "topics/Bologna/Shop-promotions"` to `"to" : "/topics/Bologna-Shop-promotions"` solved my problem. I actually found it out by checking the error while subscripting to the topic `"Bologna/Shop-promotions"` and fixed it by changing it to `"Bologna-Shop-promotions"` or `"/topics/Bologna-Shop-promotions"`. Hope this will help others.